# Use a file browser in a jfilechooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Is it possible to use a text field in a JFileChooser for browsing the operating system in a swing application?

I have already read some topics which explain the bases of the use of the class JFileChooser.
I do not know if the following link [finder files topic](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077597/learn-java/java-tip-93--add-a-file-finder-accessory-to-jfilechooser.html) is an appropriate solution for browsing files.

I know, that in Qt C++ it is possible to browse the OS with a QFileDialog.

I hope I am not too ambiguous by asking this question.

By advance, I thank all people who will be able to help me to find a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... could you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Like @J_mie6 I do not understand the requirement here.  OTOH almost anything is possible in Swing.  See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) for an example.

Comment: Now, I think I will customize my file dialog in order to be able to find a file in the OS. For example, the classes JTextField, JTable, JButton and JLabel are useful for making a file dialog.